# Jersey and Odata Key Path Param format

Tags: jersey, odata

I have a RESTful api using Jersey right now, and am converting it to be OData standard compliant. There are a few things I have not converted yet, but will get there, and is not important at this moment. One of the things I need to convert that is important is the key path params. Odata has the standard of making the key wrapped in parenthesis. So in this example myapi.com/product(1) - is the OData call to get a product whose id is 1. Currently that is possible in my system with this myapi.com/product/1

When I add the parenthesis to the path parameter I get a 404 error. My class level path is @Path("/product") and my method level path is @Path("({id})"), and use to be @Path("/{id}"). I've tried adding the parenthesis as part of the variable planning to strip them off in the method, and I've tried formatting the id with some regex @Path("{id : regex stuff}"), and neither works.

If I make my method path parameter like this @Path"/({id})") - so the call is myapi.com/product/(1), it works fine. The parenthesis is not the issue obviously. It seems the Jersey splits the uri into chunks using the forward slashes for the routing, and sense there is no forward slash between the id an root resource name, then nothing is found. It makes sense.

Is there a way to change Jerseys method of matching uri strings with some regex or something? Has anyone used Jersey with Odata? I would rather not use odata4j just for the resolution to this issue, it seems like there should be a way to get this to work.

**What I did:**
Based on Pavel Bucek's answer I did implement a ContainrRequestFilter independently to the filter I use for security. In my case I didn't look to see if existed, I just tried to do the replace.

```
    try
{
    String uriString = request.getRequestUri().toString();
    uriString = uriString.replaceAll("(\(|\)\/?)", "/");
    request.setUris(request.getBaseUri(), new URI(uriString));
} catch (final Exception e)
{
}
return request;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way how to handle this "protocol" would be introducing ContainerRequestFilter, which would replace "(*)$" with "/*$" in the incoming URI. So you will be able to serve OData and standard REST request in one app.

See http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.11/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html

Simple filter I used to test this case:

```
    rc.getProperties().put(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS, new ContainerRequestFilter() {
        @Override
        public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
            try {

                if(request.getRequestUri().toString().endsWith("(1)")) {
                    request.setUris(
                            request.getBaseUri(),
                            new URI(request.getRequestUri().toString().replace("(1)", "/1")));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return request;
        }
    });
```

both
curl "http://localhost:9998/helloworld(1)"
curl "http://localhost:9998/helloworld/1"
hit same Resource method now. (Obviously you'll need to improve current filter to be able to handle various values, but it should work for you).

Comment: We already have a filter in place so I'll see about adding this to it and give it a try thanks. I had not considered that because I thought Jersey determined the path - the resource - before hitting the filter.